# logstash multiline issue with java logs

Tags: tomcat, logging, syslog, logstash

I am installing logstash with tomcat and having issue to grab java stack trace call, following is my config

```
input   {
 udp {
   type => "tomcat"
   port => "514"
   format => "plain"

 }

}

filter{
multiline {
            pattern => "(^.+Exception.*)|(^\s+at .+)|(^\s+... \d+ more)|(^\s*Caused by:.+)"
            what => "previous"
}
}
```

Here is sample logs of tomcat

```
2014-03-24 19:08:53,246 [thread-pool8] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[engine].[localhost] - Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=500, location=/error/error500.jsp]
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:489)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:467)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:338)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:203)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1686)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.jsp.error.error500_jsp._jspService(error500_jsp.java:266)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        ... 21 more
```

I have tired all combination and none of work :( i don't know how it works for other folks..

## EDIT:

I have tried following and it didn't work too

```
pattern => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}"
       negate => true
```

following is result

```
filter received {:event=>{"message"=>"<139>2014-03-24 21:07:58,908 [] [] [thread-pool4] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[engine].[localhost] - Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=500, location=/error/error500.jsp]\n", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2014-03-25T01:07:59.128Z", "type"=>"tomcat", "host"=>"10.3.68.22"}, :level=>:debug, :file=>"(eval)", :line=>"15"}
<139>2014-03-24 21:07:58,908 [] [] [thread-pool4] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[engine].[localhost] - Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=500, location=/error/error500.jsp]
 {:pattern=>"^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} ", :match=>false, :negate=>true, :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/filters/multiline.rb", :line=>"160"}
filter received {:event=>{"message"=>"<139>org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2014-03-25T01:07:59.131Z", "type"=>"tomcat", "host"=>"10.3.68.22"}, :level=>:debug, :file=>"(eval)", :line=>"15"}
<139>org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException {:pattern=>"^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} ", :match=>false, :negate=>true, :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/filters/multiline.rb", :line=>"160"}
filter received {:event=>{"message"=>"<139>    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2014-03-25T01:07:59.134Z", "type"=>"tomcat", "host"=>"10.3.68.22"}, :level=>:debug, :file=>"(eval)", :line=>"15"}
```

## UPDATE:

I ran logstash in debug mode with udp protocol and some strange number `<139>` coming in `@messages` see following output of debug, if i use `nc` command to send sample logs it works but somehow with tomcat syslog its not working

```
{
       "message" => "<139>2014-03-28 13:52:25,548 [] [] [thread-pool2] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[engine].[localhost] - Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=500, location=/error/error500.jsp]\n",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2014-03-28T17:52:26.116Z",
          "host" => "10.3.68.22"
}
{
       "message" => "<139>org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2014-03-28T17:52:26.134Z",
          "host" => "10.3.68.22"
}
{
       "message" => "<139>    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2014-03-28T17:52:26.151Z",
          "host" => "10.3.68.22"
}
{
       "message" => "<139>    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2014-03-28T17:52:26.166Z",
          "host" => "10.3.68.22"
}
{
       "message" => "<139>    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2014-03-28T17:52:26.183Z",
          "host" => "10.3.68.22"
}
```

Comment: After multiline, what grok pattern are u applying? what fields u want logstash to absorb as fields?

Comment: Do I really need to grok in order to use multiline? I am not using any grok at this point because I just want to test first my multiline.

Comment: Multiline is implemented to let grok accept multiple lines as single entity to parse, grok is implemented to parse lines and save required fields in lucene(or NoSQL DB). Please go through [here](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/tutorials/getting-started-with-logstash) to understand usecase of logstash and you can later try on multiline.

Comment: I have update my question actually tomcat syslog sending wired number `<139>`

Comment: did u try using input "syslog" config in Logstash.conf? Docs about syslog for logstash is [here](http://www.logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/inputs/syslog)

Comment: @Murthy I have tried `syslog` but getting same code in prefix `<139>`

Comment: Each line prefixed with <139> doesn't bring any issue to your patter right. Let your pattern ignore it and parse accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether all  the logs start with a date time?

You can use it as the pattern. For example,

```
input {
    stdin {
    }
}

filter {
    multiline {
       pattern => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} "
       negate => true
       what => previous
    }
}

output {
    stdout {debug => true}
}
```

This filter is worked at me with your logs. Hope it can help you  :)

Comment: How did you test?? It didn't work for me, I am using input `udp` remote syslog

Comment: I have update my configuration, with this configuration it worked on me. I am using Logstash 1.3.3

Comment: Are you using UDP? If I use file it works but not with UDP input. Is UDP different than file? I'm using logstash 1.4.x

Comment: So it is another question. Do you want to post another question? Do you have any error message?

Comment: No error just it is just not combining multiline in single line giving me all separate timestamps for java trace call.  what input are you using?? can you please try `UDP`